# Advice needed: does it make sense to include fmt lib in header-only library?

Tags: c++, libraries, hdf5, fmt, header-only

I'm currently ending the development of a C++ header-only template library for grid-based quantum computations and I'm considering replacing an old logging module that I've wrote nearly at the beginning.

I know that it sounds a little bit weird to have a header-only library printing stuff to stdout (and files), but I make heavy use of templates to increase flexibility and efficiency of the runtime binary, hence this choice.

The current logging module uses printf (as I disliked `std::cout` syntax), macros, variadic macros (`##__VA_ARGS__`), supports console colors and prints out the the location in the source using  `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` macros, i.e. nothing modern nor type safe, but it works.

Does it make sense replace it with `fmt` (or something similar) or should I rather try to modernize the existing one (i.e. replace variadic macros with templates, custom built compile-time `string_view`'s etc.)?

I'd like the library to work "straight-away" that is, I'd like to either:

a) eliminate as much dependencies as possible

b) try `find_package(fmt)` or FetchContent them silently in CMake - (btw. is there a general CMake "template" for this behaviour? something like "find_or_fetch"? )

c) place the essential part of `fmt` as a git submodule in my project and include a small header file.

Beside this, I'm also planning to use HDF5 library (with or without C++ wrappers).
Here again I'm not sure how to best approach it to make the integration as seamless as possible, neither have I decided which wrapper should I use.
Would a "find_or_fetch" paradigm be appropriate for header-only library?

Comment: FWIW, C++20 has included the fmt library as part of it, and there is also [`<source_location>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which you can use to get rid of the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I'm aware of this. This is why I've postponed the upgrade of this logging module till the end. The problem is... I can't require C++20. This is painful, but university stuff is almost always very sluggish in updating stuff. Edit: on the other hand I could set additional requirements on debug options such as previewing source location... Nevertheless regular console logging still needs to be done.

Comment: Just as an idea of what I do: For logging, if c++20 does not exists, I don't show line numbers and files. That might be annoying if someone can't use c++20, but I prefer not to use macros because you risk name conflicts or you need to use long names. For `fmt` I would go with **b** but only if is not compiled with c++20.  **c)** can be problematic if the project using your library also uses `fmt`.

Comment: A little off-topic, but since you are asking for advice: While you are refactoring your logging module, I would go one step further switch to `spdlog`, which comes with a packaged copy of `fmt`. Less code in the project itself, and it's highly unlikely that your implementation edges it out in any metric.

Comment: @Frank thanks, I've seen `spdlog` and I'm considering using it as well, but then what happens when C++20 becomes more widely adopted?

Comment: @t.niese that's the pain... How does one exactly make a fallback from c++20 to `fmt`  without repeating nearly the same code twice?

Comment: @Ranza Eventually https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/1932 will be complete and the library will transparently use `<format>` instead. The key point is that fmt is not used directly, but abstracted away as an implementation detail of the library.

Comment: @Frank thank you, that's terrific news! One problem remains, namely it is somehow distasteful to install/download a large library just to be able to use a minimalistic header-only library which is my code.

Comment: spdlog is arguably a minimalistic header-only library itself...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235315/discussion-between-ranza-and-frank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't if I were you.

- A header-only library implies being minimalistic. `fmt` is the opposite of that.
- A header-only library implies being user-friendly. Forcing a large dependency on a user isn't very friendly.
- If you've gone that far without needing better logging tools, chances are, the tools you are using are already good enough.
- Having to match format strings and arguments is one of the largest drawbacks of not using `fmt`. But you've done that matching already. And modern compilers warn about any mismatches as long as format strings are literals.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense if you do a lot of formatting and [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) is designed to support easy embedding. In particular, it has zero dependencies and is relatively small with the minimal configuration consisting of just three moderate-size files. There are several projects that embed {fmt}, for example, [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog). One advantage compared to rolling out your own formatting solution is that it will be easy to port to `std::format` in the future.